# What is the equivalent to shift-drag/duplicate brush in MS Paint for Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]

Do you remember this effect on MS Paint? I really want to do this on Photoshop but not sure what the hotkey is. Can someone help? :)

Comment: I don't think there is a "hotkey" for such a thing in Photoshop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `Mixer Brush` with a hard round tip, 0% `Wetness`, 100% `Load`, 100% `Flow` and 1% `Spacing`. And changing `Spacing` will make a distance between samples larger:

[image]

This is actually a great way to draw cables, ground details and similar things; as well as introducing some noise to paintings...%)

[image]

Comment: This is such an excellent way to make such an effect! Are there other alternatives to create interesting textures?

Comment: Well, maybe a `Pattern Stamp` tool with an `Impressionist` option turned on and a not too contrast image as a pattern

Comment: Ah, also a `Smudge Tool` with `Strength` set to 100% and no `Shape Dynamics`